# c# windows form app, problem with replacing string

Tags: c#

I am writing a windows form app in C#. I have a label with a random word, e.g. "computer". User has to guess what is this word by guessing letter by letter. But word "computer" must be replaced with as many "x" as there is letters in a word, so in this example user should see "xxxxxxxx".

Then user types letter, e.g. types "c", so on the screen would be "cxxxxxxx", after that user types "m" and it would be "cxmxxxxx".

I tried to write a code, but it does not work as I expected.

```
        public static string StrMultiply(string source, int multiplier)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(multiplier * source.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(source);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

This function allowes to multiply strings, it helps me to write "x" on the screen.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            correct = word.Text; //correct word before replacing
            wordLen = correct.Length; //length of correct word
            word.Text = Regex.Replace(word.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$", StrMultiply("x",wordLen)); //replace string with 'x'
        }

        private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (correct.Contains(tb.Text)) //check if user types correct letter
            {
                result.Text = "Good!";
                var idx = correct.IndexOf(tb.Text);
                word.Text.Remove(idx, 1);
                word.Text = StrMultiply("x", idx) + tb.Text + word.Text.Substring(idx+1); //<- Error
            }
            else
            {
                result.Text = "Not good :(";
            }

        }
```

When user guesses a letter on the screen he would see "cxxxxxxx", but then types "m" and "c" is replayced with "x", so in the screen there is "xxmxxxxx". Program works only if user types letters right to left, because correct letters don't change to "x".

Problem is with function StrMultiply in this line:

```
word.Text = StrMultiply("x", idx) + tb.Text + word.Text.Substring(idx+1);
```

I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: hint : use boolean array to reveal value. for example, computer for bool[8], use true/false for masking each letter as 'x'

Comment: @Arphile thats not my homework, it's just my idea to do this program, i will try with boolean

Comment: There is a string constructor that will replace your `StrMultiply()`, like this: `word.Text = new String('x', "computer".Length);`

Answer (score 0):

word = word.Substring(0, idx) + tb.Text + word.Substring(idx + 1, word.Length - idx - 1);`you can try this way. does not work for multiple repeating characters.`

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this. There is already a [string constructor that will do what you need](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correct = word.Text; //correct word before replacing
    wordLen = correct.Length; //length of correct word
    word.Text = new String('x', wordLen);
}
```

I also see an attempt to only look at letters, and leave punctuation, numbers, and whitespace alone. However, the regular expression also pinned to both the beginning and end of the string, meaning the expression would fail to match at all if there were any non-alpha characters.

We can fix that by only matching on each letter, and only replacing that letter, like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correct = word.Text; //correct word before replacing
    wordLen = correct.Length; //length of correct word
    word.Text = Regex.Replace(correct, @"[a-zA-Z]", "x"); 
}
```

In both cases, the `StrMultiply()` function is not needed.

As far as *unmasking*, what I might do is build the regular expression on the fly after each guess. While I'm at it, would use something other than `x`, for words where `x` is part of the text:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correct = word.Text; //correct word before replacing
    wordLen = correct.Length; //length of correct word
    ShowWord();
}

private string Mask = "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]";
private void ShowWord()
{
    word.Text = Regex.Replace(correct, mask, "*"); 
}

private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I assume you have some way to make sure there's only one letter here
    if (!correct.Contains(tb.Text)) //check if user types correct letter
    {
        result.Text = "Not good :(";
        return;
    }

    result.Text = "Good!";
    // remove the guess from the Mask
    Mask = Mask.Replace(tb.Text, "", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    ShowWord();
}
```

Comment: I have an erorr in line:

`Mask = Mask.Replace(tb.Text, "", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`

CS1501: no overload of the "Replace" method takes the following number of arguments: "3"

Comment: @keyboardNoob What version of .Net are you using, because there definitely is such an overload. Here is the documentation for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Comment: Hmm... 4.6 is pretty old, but this overload seems to be a .Net Core 2.0 / .Net 5 addition. The alternative is manually checking the case on your `tb.Text` value, to make sure you get both UPPER/lower versions in the mask. And, again, I've also assumed you've done work to make sure `tb.Text` only has one character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to reveal a letter:

```
private string UncoverLetter(string correctWord, string coveredWord, char letter)
{
    var correctWordArr = correctWord.ToCharArray();
    var coveredWordArr = coveredWord.ToCharArray();

    for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < correctWordArr.Length; charIndex++)
    {
        if (correctWord[charIndex] == letter)
        {
            coveredWordArr[charIndex] = letter;
        }
    }

    return coveredWordArr.ToString();
}
```

you can just call this function by passing the correct word (computer), the covered word (cxmxxxxx) and the letter to uncover, and it would return the covered word with uncovering the new letter.